# Multiple SELECT Statements and INSERTS in 1 file

Tags: php, mysql, sql, mysqli

I'm working with a file and I'm attempting to do multiple select statements one after another and insert some values. So far the insert and the select I've got working together but when attempting to get the last SELECT to work I get no value. Checking the SQL query in workbench and everything works fine. Here's the code:

```
$id = "SELECT idaccount FROM `animator`.`account` WHERE email = '$Email'";
$result = mysqli_query($dbc, $id) or die("Error: ".mysqli_error($dbc));
while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result))
{
    echo $row[0];
    $insert_into_user = "INSERT INTO `animator`.`user` (idaccount) VALUES ('$row[0]')";
}
    $select_userid = "SELECT iduser FROM `animator`.`user` WHERE iduser = '$row[0]'";

    $results = mysqli_query($dbc, $select_userid) or die("Error: ".mysqli_error($dbc));
while($rows = mysqli_fetch_array($results))
{    
    echo $rows[0];
}
```

I do not want to use $mysqli->multi_query because of previous problems I ran into. Any suggestions? And yes I know the naming conventions are close naming... They will be changed shortly.

Comment: So you want us to debug your code?

Comment: I'm asking if anyone could help which is the point of this community. If not I will close the question. I'm not asking someone to complete the work for me I'm looking for some advice to help me advance.

Comment: Well here goes an advice: debug your code.

Comment: dump/echo all the queries and make sure they contain the right values.  your `SELECT iduser` query isn't in the `while` loop so `$row[0]` may not hold the value you think it does.  also i'm not sure you actually execute `$insert_into_user` anywhere...?

Comment: `WHERE iduser = '$row[0]'` shouldn't this be `WHERE idaccount = '$row[0]'`, given you inserted it to `idaccount`.

Comment: what is this code actually supposed to do?  it looks like... you run a query for a certain email.  then, for every ID you get back, you want to insert a row into the user table (but these inserts are never executed in your code)... then, you want to pull that new ID out of the table you just inserted to... is that correct?

Comment: Afaik `= '$row[0]'` is invalid synthax. It would result in the string `= 'Array[0]'`. If you want to get values from the array, you should either separate and do `='".$row[0]."'` or use `= '{$row[0]}'`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your code makes no sense. You repeatedly build/re-build the `$insert_int-User` query, and then NEVER actually execute the query. The $select_userid query will use only the LAST retrieved $row[0] value from the first query. Since that last "row" will be a boolean FALSE to signify that no more data is available `$row[0]` will actually be trying to de-reference that boolean FALSE as an array.

Since you're effectively only doing 2 select queries (or at least trying to), why not re-write as a single two-value joined query?

```
SELECT iduser, idaccount
FROM account
LEFT JOIN user ON user.iduser=account.idaccount
WHERE email='$Email';
```

Comment: the table user doesn't have email in it. I Have to compare the value of email in the account table first and then use the compared value to find the correct userid under the user table. I know it's stupidly complicated and should be cleaned up.

Comment: Sorry, missed the two different tables. Use a joined query. I've modded my sample query

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure what you're trying to do in your code exactly but that a look at this...

```
// create select statement to get all accounts where email=$Email from animator.account
$id_query = "SELECT idaccount FROM animator.account WHERE email = '$Email'";
echo $id_query."\n"; 

// run select statement for email=$mail 
$select_results = mysqli_query($dbc, $id_query) or die("Error: ".mysqli_error($dbc));


// if we got some rows back from the database... 
if ($select_results!==false)
{ 
   $row_count = 0; 

   // loop through all results 
   while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result))
   {
       $idaccount = $row[0]; 

       echo "\n\n-- Row #$row_count --------------------------------------------\n";
       echo $idaccount."\n";

       // create insert statement for this idaccount
       $insert_into_user = "INSERT INTO animator.user (idaccount) VALUES ('$idaccount')"; 
       echo $insert_into_user."\n";

       // run insert statement for this idaccount
       $insert_results = mysqli_query($dbc, $insert_into_user) or die("Error: ".mysqli_error($dbc)); 

       // if our insert statement worked... 
       if ($insert_results!==false)
       {
          // Returns the auto generated id used in the last query
          $last_inisert_id = mysqli_insert_id($dbc); 
          echo $last_inisert_id."\n"; 
       }
       else 
       { 
         echo "insert statement did not work.\n"; 
       }

       $row_count++; 
   }

}
// we didn't get any rows back from the DB for email=$Email 
else 
{ 
   echo "select query returned no results...? \n"; 
}
```